# Wordpress variable concatenation then re-use in foreach

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, concatenation

I am having a few issues concatenating a string and then outputting the value.

In the database I have a column titled `'featured_price'`. In that column is specified another column that will hold the value I am trying to acquire, however, I need to append `'_term'` to the end and then get the column from the database.

So I need to have two outputs:

**1) featured_price** 
**2) specified_column_term**

This is my PHP:

```
 $rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM specified_details WHERE id='$id'"); 
 foreach ($rows as $result) { 
     echo $result->featured_price;

     $featuredprice = $result->featured_price;
     $featuredterm  = $featuredprice. "_term";

     echo $result->$featuredterm;
 }
```

When I `var_dump()` I just get this `array(0)`.

Comment: can you show `var_dump($result)` also

Comment: it outputs the entire table, which is more than the comment space that is allowed. However, here are the two fields that I need in there :  ["featured_price"]=> string(10) "fl_price_3" and ["fl_price_3"]=> string(4) "3000"

Comment: you can edit the question also and add it to that, but based on the output you shown i don't see anywhere there is a `_term` field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a mistake there on line

```
echo $result->$featuredterm;
```

Shouldnt it be

```
echo $rows->$featuredterm;
```

?

Comment: are you going by the name of the variable or are you looking at the code?